# Unauthorized request does not redirect to login page with returnUrl query string parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, returnurl

### Setup

In my MVC3 app, MembersController is decorated with an [Authorize] attribute.

MembersController has an Action called MyPage.  Due to the Authorize attribute on the controller, MyPage can only be requested by authorized users.

### Problem

When an unauthorized user tries to request /Members/MyPage they are correctly redirected to the Login page.

However, the ReturnUrl parameter is not passed into the login page, so when the user authenticates, they are taken to the default page (lets call it /Members/Home) instead of /Members/MyPage.

### Question

Why?!

In another app, developed in MVC2, the returnUrl QS parameters is there and works as expected.

### Other Issues:

The Autorize attribute is being ignored when decorating both controllers and actions.

### Resolution:

Sections of web.config not properly updated between .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.  See answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Marcind put me on the right track, @Darin Dimitrov's answer very instructive of the process involved.

### Diagnosis

It seems that the issue was related to a web.config that I did not update properly when merging an existing Web Forms .NET 3.5 app to a .NET 4.0 app.  I can't recall how I went about this.

Anyway, by comparing the web.config of my app with a new MVC 3 web.config, I was able to find the extra bits that should not have been there, left over from 3.5 days.

### Resolution:

The issue was resolved by correcting the bits in the <authentication><forms> tag in the web.config, as well as the <membership> tag.

### Other Issues Caused by this:

Another issue caused by this was the fact that if I decorated a controller with the Authorize attribute, it was ignored, so the controller tried to process info based on the current user, that obviously was null, so all manner of exceptions were fired.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. I created a new project using the ASP.NET MVC 3 RC2, default template, added a MembersController, decorated it with the `[Authorize]` attribute, run the application, requested `/members/index`, was redirected to `/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fmembers%2findex`, logged in, was redirected to `/members/index`. There must be something else wrong with your code.

Here's how it works:

- The `[Authorize]` attribute checks if the user is authenticated and if it is not it returns 401 status code.
- The [FormsAuthenticationModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationmodule.aspx) which is part of ASP.NET and handles forms authentication intercepts the 401 status code and redirects to the login page by appending the ReturnUrl parameter to the request which points to the initial request.

The `FormsAuthenticationModule` module is not specific to ASP.NET MVC, this is standard ASP.NET stuff

Comment: Thanks for answering Darin.  I agree that the problem is my code, but where, I have no idea.  Is there any place where you can configure or override the FormsAuthenticationModule?  What can I have done to override this behaviour?

Comment: Easiest way would be to compare your web.config files and global.asax with the ones in a brand new RC2 project.

Comment: @marcind: So obvious but put me on right track. See my answer.  Many thanks.

Comment: thanks the detail in your answer, very instructive, but would be misleading to tick it as the accepted answer.